# Azure Pipeline checkout same repo multiple times

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've been banging my head for DAYS on this.
Basically, this is my setup:

- I have a master pipeline that is divided in 10-15 stages, you can select which ones to run.
- All stages depend on 1 Powershell stage which does some work and sets some variables
- Each stage (except the Powershell one) calls a template, which calls another BIG template (some stages may call the same BIG template or a different one)
- My problem resides on the "checkout" step:

```
- checkout: git://Project/${{parameters.RepositoryToCheckOut}}@$(Build.SourceBranch)
   path: PathSpecified
```

Both the branch and repository variables need to be dynamic in some way.

This step is performed multiple times if two or more stages are selected, which prompts this error on Azure DevOps:

```
An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. An item with the same key has already been added.
```

I read on some documents that it's some kind of key/value issue and I have no idea how to overcome it. I want to **refrain** from using a simple bash step and manually checkout since these files are very important and there's no margin for error.

What could be a solution to this?

I tried using parameters and compile time variables but nothing worked. I still have the same error.

Comment: It seems unnecessary to check out the repo multiple times. Check it out once, do the things you need to do, publish the build artifacts, and then consume your artifacts in the subsequent stages.

Comment: Problem is that the subsequent stages run with multiple other agents, so the checkout needs to be done multiple times. In any case, we resolved the issue by doing this: `- checkout: git://ProjectName/${{parameters.RepositoryToCheckout}}@${{ variables['Build.SourceBranch'] }}
`

Comment: It's unclear why you are trying to do what you are doing, but maybe you could publish everything as a pipeline artifact in one of the first stages and then just download those files in subsequent stages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue was solved by using this:

```
- checkout: git://ProjectName/${{parameters.RepositoryToCheckout}}@${{ variables['Build.SourceBranch'] }}
```

Apparently this tricks the pipeline and it just works, I can't even explain it properly myself to be honest.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and fixed like described above.
To understand what i changed:

```
checkout: git://ProjectName/${{parameters.RepositoryToCheckout}}@$(Build.SourceBranch)
```

Was changed to

```
- checkout: git://ProjectName/${{parameters.RepositoryToCheckout}}@${{ variables['Build.SourceBranch'] }}
```

It seems the compiler handles that different. Why? I also do not know and not understand... but it works..